# How to find what js is applying?

Tags: cart, javascript, ajax, jquery, script

please visit [here](http://hotwheelstoys.in/2/em0113-full-package/index.php/slr-camera-tripod.html)

click on "Buy Now" button, than you will see "**Check**" button in cart page.

once you enter the zip code " 560043" and enter "check" button, than you can see its calculating shipping charges

some Jquery code is the reason for this, but i want to know what jquery is there behind this feature

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following jquery applying on clicking on *check*

```
//<![CDATA[
    var coShippingMethodForm = new VarienForm('shipping-zip-form');
    var countriesWithOptionalZip = ["IN"];

    function getshippingcost()
    {
        //alert(document.getElementById('postcode1').value);
        document.getElementById('postcode').value=document.getElementById('postcode1').value;
        var country = $F('country');
        var optionalZip = false;

        for (i=0; i < countriesWithOptionalZip.length; i++) {
            if (countriesWithOptionalZip[i] == country) {
                optionalZip = true;
            }
        }
        if (optionalZip) {
            $('postcode').removeClassName('required-entry');
        }
        else {
            $('postcode').addClassName('required-entry');
        }
        return VarienForm.prototype.submit.bind(coShippingMethodForm)();
    }   

//]]>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: how you found that ? where is the option through inspect element to find this ?

Comment: There  is function `onClick` on `getshippingcost()`. So i just found this function in page source. That's it

Comment: okay in `"view page source"` , thats great , thanks.